# How to navigate to different views on click of rows in two different sections in a tableview?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have two different sections in a tableview. I want to navigate to two different viewcontrollers on click of rows in different sections. I know that this can be accomplished in didSelectRowAtIndexPath() method but i am thinking on how to differentiate the click of rows in different sections.Can u please help me if this can be implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a **`switch`** statement to determine the section of the `UITableView`.

### Example:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    switch ( indexPath.section )
    {  
        case 0:
        {
            FirstViewController * first = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController: first animated: YES];
        }
            break;
        case 1:
        {
            SecondViewController * second = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController: second animated: YES];
        }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: The previous answer before editing will do for me...i do want to navigate to different views based on different sections selected but not depending on the rows inside the sections. Anyhow thanks for the help again...

Comment: :) Thanks WrightsCS. I have voted and accepted ur answer..can u please do the same?

Answer (score 1):

Do Something like this in you didSelectRowtIndexPath :-

```
if (indexPath.section==0 && indexPath.row==0) {
    //Do Something
}
```

Or you can use switch case.

Comment: Ya.Thanks i guess the above would help but can u please post the code how to use the swith case?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UIViewController *viewController;
    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0: 
            viewController = [[[FirstExampleViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
            break;
        case 1: 
            viewController = [[[SecondExampleViewController alloc] init] autorelease]; 
            break;
        case 2:
            viewController = [[[ThirdExampleViewController alloc] init] autorelease]; 
            break;
        default: 
            viewController = [[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    } 
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: The above mentioned logic works fine for the differentiation shown when different rows are clicked..but my requirement is to navigate based on the sections. Anyhow thanks for the help. I got my answer...

Comment: just have to change indexPath.row to indexPath.section for your above comment